# Jquery datatable Date Column Sorting not Sorting based on recent Dates

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Iam new to Jquery
Using a Jquery plugin called [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/index).
Here im getting a sorting issue in Date Column.
In my project, i want to sort column based on recent dates.
But it was sorting from top to bottom and bottom to top
Can anyone help please?
Thanks

```
 jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {

        "date-uk-pre": function ( a ) {
            var ukDatea = a.split('/');

            return (ukDatea[0] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[2]) * 1;
        },

        "date-uk-asc": function ( a, b ) {
            //alert(a)
            //var ukDatea = a.split('/');
            //if(ukDatea[2])
            return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
        },

        "date-uk-desc": function ( a, b ) {
            return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

For use this plugin, you should import the js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/sorting/date-uk.js"></script>
```

and especified the column that contain the date.

```
......
columnDefs: [
   { type: 'date-uk', targets: 0 }
 ]
......
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/31/

If you want one example whitout extern js try...

http://live.datatables.net/lorituwu/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the sorting issue with php.

```
$mydate = strtotime($startdate);
$newformat = date('d-m-Y',$mydate);
echo '<tr>';
echo '  <td data-sort="'. $mydate .'">'.$newformat .'</td>';
```